# Getting ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED on _some_ files in a folder

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Peculiar case: I have an inherited WordPress install (on NGINX), where *some* of the .svg files refuse to show, and give a ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED instead.

works: https://fatstickboards.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/credit-cards/test.svg

doesn't work: https://fatstickboards.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/icons/credit-cards/visa.svg

There's nothing in the config that I can find to explain this. It's as if it depends on the contents of the .svg file...?

Comment: I just get a 403 Forbidden error, that on inspection says that you have blocked the user agent in CloudFlare. And that's after I ignore the SSL certificate warning.

Comment: None of that is intentional. I didn't even know one could block user agents in Cloudflare  :)

SSL is handled by Cloudflare, but the server itself should have a valid (let's encrypt) certificate as well.
What SSL cert are you seeing on the site?

Comment: Ahh, the SSL thing was a red herring. So what I'm seeing is an extremely long delay of a couple of minutes before the server finally sends the SVG file, but without a content length. This suggests that your web server is not sending the static file, but trying to process it through PHP. Show your complete web server configuration.

Comment: Both work perfectly for me, and load immediately. Chrome on PC, fast internet connection in New Zealand. What's giving the decoding error, the browser or the server? It's very unlikely to be Wordpress.

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem is somewhere within Cloudflare. Putting the site in Development Mode (disables caching) didn't help, but pausing (turns off all Cloudflare except for DNS) works.

I guess it's now time for trial and error to determine which Cloudflare component is the culprit.

The problem is that it can take 5-10 minutes at times before changes are active, so this will be a lengthy process...  :-/